# make directory with two bash variable as shown below, what's wrong?

Tags: bash

Can't make directory with the following bash script:

```
##! /bin/bash
PROJ=~/myname
for i in  aa bb cc
do
TMPDIR=${PROJ}/${i}
test ! -e ${TMPDIR} &&  mkdir ${TMPDIR}
OUTDIR=${PROJ}/${i}/subfolder
test ! -e ${OUTDIR} &&  mkdir ${OUTDIR}

/bin/cp -f ./file.out ${OUTDIR}/
done
```

It turns out the OUTDIR dose not exist!
What's wrong, and how do I make directory with two bash variable?

thanks in advance.

Comment: `PROJ=~/home` will expand to `/home/user/home` -- Is that what you want? If it is, all you need is `for i in aa bb cc; do mkdir -p $PROJ/$I/subfolder || exit 1; cp -f file.out $PROJ/$I/subfolder; done` (**note:** the `-p` create parent directories as needed)

Comment: Bad example. I've change to PROJ=~/myname, which stands for my project directory. It it nothing to do with home directory. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: OK. You will get `/home/youruser/myname` as the project directory. The environment variable `$HOME` already provides `/home/youruser`, so what you really want is `$HOME/myname`.

Answer (score 1):

And you did not get any error message, that a directory can not be created? After all, your script would fail if the the directory `$HOME/home` does not exist.

You could simplify the creation process to

```
PROJ="$HOME/home"
for i in  aa bb cc
do
  OUTDIR="$PROJ/$i/subfolder"
  mkdir -p "$OUTDIR" && cp -f ./file.out "$OUTDIR" && echo "File copied to $OUTDIR"
done
```

Comment: I suspect `/home/user/home` did not exist so `mkdir ${TMPDIR}` failed due to not using the `-p` option.  (you may want to explain the use of a *compound command* (e.g. `command && command && command ...`)

Comment: I thought so too, but in this case, mkdir would have issued an error message, and the OP does not mention one. BTW, that's the reason why I explicitly asked in my posting about the error message. And, it might well be that /home/user/home **does** exist. What do we mere humans know how the OP is naming his directories? Home is where my home is .... Side note: I didn't explain compound commands, because the OP already uses them in his code and hence is familiar with them.

Comment: Bad example. I've change to PROJ=~/myname, which stands for my project directory. It it nothing to do with home directory. Sorry for the confusion.